# How to access <dc:creator> from a RSS XML feed using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, rss, nokogiri

Using Nokogiri I am able to access XML elements as follows:

```
feed = "https://www.coachesvoice.com/category/masterclass/feed/"

# Using HTTParty to get the the feed and save it as rss
rss = HTTParty.get(feed)

# Using Nokogiri to parse the returned rss feed and save it as doc
doc = Nokogiri::XML(rss)

doc.css('item').take(2).each do |item|

    # set title to the item's title element text

    title = item.css('title').text


end
```

But when attempting to access the `<dc:creator>` element I am left with an empty variable.

This does not work:

```
  # set creator to the item's dc:creator element
        # creator = item.css('dc:creator').text
```

Nor does this

```
# set creator to the item's dc:creator element
        # creator = item.css('dc_creator').text
```

Any help to figure out how I can access this element would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Nokogiri's docs are not for the timid, that's for sure, but the samples are priceless and working through them will help immensely. I'd recommend reading from https://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces to the end of the document and playing with the examples. In addition, there are numerous examples here on SO explaining how to deal with namespaces.

Comment: Just as a hint, it's not necessary to use Httparty to get the HTML content then pass it to Nokogiri. Nokogiri can read from an open file handle, which typically we do from OpenURI. It saves a little time-space continuum. Again, the tutorials demonstrate it.

Comment: And, unless this is just an exercise, I'd recommend looking into using some existing code rather than recreate that wheel. RSS flavors vary and most feed generators do the wrong things, and then you have to account for Atom feeds. I wrote a RSS/Atom parser that was handling thousands of feeds a day and it can get pretty nasty out there.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks a lot for this--meant to respond some time ago

Answer (score 2):

```
creator = item.css("dc|creator").text
```

Ref https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attrnmsp

Comment: This is basically a link-only answer. Instead, add the pertinent information from the link to your answer, and include the appropriate attribution to the author. That way, *when* the link breaks the answer will still have some value. Without that information it'll be worthless to future searches for help. Explain how Nokogiri uses namespaces, or, again, provide a reference to that information and how to deal with it. It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code or a link.